# Extension for WYSIWYG in Joomla for end-users

Tags: joomla

i'm very new to Joomla and wondering if there is an extension for displaying a WYSIWYG editor for my end-users. I need my end-users to upload image of products, write in their comments and submit.I need some auto-responding mechanism to email me, (the administrator) that user A has submitted an article. I will then read and approve his article. when approved, the article will be displayed on the website for all users to view this article.

Is this possible in Joomla? I'm just starting up and wondering how difficult is this to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need a component(type of Joomla extension) for this. There are thousands of extensions to choose from at on the Joomla Extensions Directory. Have a look on there, test a few and see which ones suit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WYSIWYG is built in to Joomla. Select the editor under Global Configuration - Site
(Personally I use JCE which you will find in the Joomla Extensions site.)

The rest of what you want to do is also built in - Google Joomla Moderation. There are many options so either build a test site and play or look for some online tutorials.